# Python simple backpropagation not working as expected

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to implement the backpropagation algorithm to show how a two layered neural network can be used to behave as the XOR logic gate. I followed this tutorial [here](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/).

After running, I expect the output to follow the [XOR](https://logic.ly/lessons/xor-gate/) logic truth table:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]]
```

However I get:

```
output after training:  [[0.5]
 [0.5]
 [0.5]
 [0.5]]
```

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong? Thanks

---

Full code:

```
import numpy as np


# Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))


# Input dataset
X = np.array([[0, 0],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 1]])

# Output dataset
y = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

# seed random numbers to make calculation deterministic
np.random.seed(1)

# initialise weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((2, 1)) - 1

for iter in range(10000):

    # forward prop
    layer0 = X
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, syn0))

    layer1_error = y - layer1

    layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid(layer1, True)

    syn0 += np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta)
    print(iter)

print("output after training: ", layer1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done nothing wrong - you've correctly demonstrated that a single layer ANN cannot perform [non-linear separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability)!

XOR inputs are an example of data that is not linearly separable - simply put, if you plot them on an x-y grid, you can't draw a straight line to separate the "0" outputs from the "1" outputs. A single layer artificial neural network can only perform linear separation, so will fail to produce the correct output regardless of how you train it.

To solve the XOR problem you need to add an extra layer. It seems like you have two layers already (the input layer and the output layer), but it's actually a single layer network because there is only one layer of weights (`syn0`). Add a second layer (following the example in the reference you provided) and see if the training results improve.